# How to enlarge logo in a mobile view?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I want to enlarge a logo in a mobile view so that it does not get smaller with responsiveness. How can I do this? I tried `max-width:200%` but it does not seem to work well.

Comment: If you have a code sample that would be great.

There's no way to give you a proper response without knowing whether or not the logo is an inline image, or the background image of a div.

If you already have media queries setup, you would simply change the width via a CSS property.

Comment: `max-width:200%` just means that your logo is allowed to have a maximum width of 200%. You're not setting it's size to 200%.
Share some code and picture of what you want to achieve and we'll be able to help you better.